# how to register and call the external javascript function in jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I've a scenario like

```
 user logs in ( /login)

 navigate to the reservations page to get all the reservation id (/reservations)

  Through json path extractor it gets first reservation id from the JSON.($..reservationLists..id[0], reservationid)

  navigate to the first reservation id (/reservation/${reservationid})
```

In every page it navigates , the HTTP header manager needs the handShakeKey applicable to that page which is basically combination of url, secretKey, publicKey. ( secretKey , publicKey are both static but url changes )

For static urls like ( /login, /reservations) I've added a BSF pre-processor at beginning and declare variables and use those variables in the HTTP Header Manager as ${handshakeKey_reservations}, ${handshakeKey_login} etc which  works perfectly fine.

```
  var urls = ["login", "reservations", "logout", "profile"];

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    var handShakeKeyForStaticUrls = CryptoJS.SHA1("/"+urls[i]+"abcdediiebneC"+"12345678");

      handShakeKeyForStaticUrls = handShakeKeyForStaticUrls.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

     vars.put("handshakeKey_"+urls[i], handShakeKeyForStaticUrls);

      }
```

Now the problem is for Dynamic url (/reservation/${reservationid}, /reservation/${reservationid}/summary etc.......)

I was thinking to write a java script function something like

```
    function getHandShakeKey(url)
       {

       var handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls = CryptoJS.SHA1(url+"abcdeffe"+"12345678");

       handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls = handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

       //return handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls;

      vars.put("handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls", handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls);

       }
```

Then in the HTTP header manager I would do like

handshakeKey     ${_javaScript(getHandShakeKey("/reservation/${reservationid}"))}

So question is Where I can register this java script function so that I can call it everywhere .

Though the workaround I've done is at the moment, adding a BSF post processor to each http sampler which contains dynamic url and generating and declaring handShakeKey applicable for that url only and using the same in the corresponding HTTP header manager. I need to get rid of this.

Comment: Any thoughts on this please

Comment: Is this actually possible to register the external java scripts and call the functions from that java script globally everywhere.

Comment: Does beanshell.function.init  allow to register javascipt class/methods so that we can call it globally anywhere.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? If yes, then please share.